# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable for dateFormat with scala 2.10

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

This was working when i used scala version 2.11, but when i downgraded to 2.10, this is not working.even though i was using json4s v2.10 of scala.

I tried adding native formats, but could not succeed. can someone throw some info of how to fix it.

---

```
package com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import com.golfbreaks.quote.Quote
import com.google.gson.{Gson, GsonBuilder}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.native.JsonParser


object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
      //DefaultFormats

    val zkQuorum = "quickstart.cloudera"
    val topics = "sf_quotes"
    val group = "group1"
    val numThreads = 2
    val tableName: TableName = TableName.valueOf("sf_quotes")

    //val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("GolfBreaksStreamingQuotes")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    val gson: Gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create()

    val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
      .filter(_._2 != null)
      .map {
        //case (_, json) => Quote.parseQuote(json)
        //case (_, json) => json
        //read[Quote](json)
        case (_, json) => JsonParser.parse(json).extract[Quote]
      }
    //.reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Minutes(1), Seconds(2), 2)
    //lines.foreachRDD( rdd => rdd.foreach(println))

    //println(json);

    /*val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "instance-26765.bigstep.io,instance-26766.bigstep.io,instance-26767.bigstep.io")
    conf.set("hbase.master", "instance-26765.bigstep.io:60000")
    conf.setInt("timeout", 120000)*/

    //lines.print()

    lines.transform(rdd => {
      val hbaseTableName = "sf_quotes"
      //Creates the HBase confs
      val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
      hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "quickstart.cloudera")
      //hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "instance-26765.bigstep.io,instance-26766.bigstep.io,instance-26767.bigstep.io,instance-26768.bigstep.io")
      hconf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
      hconf.set("hbase.defaults.for.version.skip", "true")
      val job = Job.getInstance(hconf)
      val jobConf = job.getConfiguration
      jobConf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName.getNameAsString)
      job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[ImmutableBytesWritable]])
      //hconf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, hbaseTableName)
      //hconf.setClass("mapreduce.job.outputformat.class", classOf[TableOutputFormat[String]], classOf[OutputFormat[String, Mutation]])

      /*rdd.map {
        jsonStr => gson.fromJson(jsonStr,classOf[Quote])
      }*/
      rdd.map(quote => (new ImmutableBytesWritable, {

        val quoteColumnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("quote")
        val putRecord = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(quote.Id))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Id"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Id))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Name"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Name))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Opportunity__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Opportunity__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Account__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Account__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalesChannel__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalesChannel__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("PrimaryVenue__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.PrimaryVenue__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalesRegion__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalesRegion__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalePriceGross__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalePriceGross__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("CostPriceGross__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.CostPriceGross__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("GrossProfit__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.GrossProfit__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("GrossProfitPercent__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.GrossProfitPercent__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("NumberOfGuest__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.NumberOfGuest__c))
        putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Gross_profit_per_person__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Gross_profit_per_person__c))

        putRecord
      }
      )
      ).saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(jobConf)
      rdd
    }).print()
    println("**************************************************************")
    ssc.start()
    println("start Streaming")
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

### // scalastyle:on println

```
package com.golfbreaks.quote

import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

/**
  * Created by rapolu on 07/03/2017.
  */
case class Quote(Id: String,
                 Name: String = "",
                 Opportunity__c: String = "",
                 Account__c: String = "",
                 SalesChannel__c: String = "",
                 PrimaryVenue__c: String = "",
                 SalesRegion__c: String = "",
                 SalePriceGross__c: String = "0.0",
                 CostPriceGross__c: String = "0.0",
                 GrossProfit__c: String = "0.0",
                 GrossProfitPercent__c: String = "0.0",
                 NumberOfGuest__c: String = "0",
                 Gross_profit_per_person__c: String = "0.0") extends Serializable



object Quote extends Serializable{
  def parseQuote(str: String):Unit = {
    def apply(r: Row): Quote =
      Quote(r.getString(0),r.getString(1),r.getString(2),r.getString(3),r.getString(4),r.getString(5),r.getString(6),
        r.getString(7),r.getString(8),r.getString(9),r.getString(10), r.getString(11),r.getString(12)
        //,        r.getString(13),r.getString(13)
      )
  }

  def convertToPut(quote: Quote): (ImmutableBytesWritable,Put) = {
    val quoteColumnFamily = Bytes.toBytes("quote")
    val putRecord = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(quote.Id))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Id"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Id))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Name"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Name))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Opportunity__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Opportunity__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Account__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Account__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalesChannel__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalesChannel__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("PrimaryVenue__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.PrimaryVenue__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalesRegion__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalesRegion__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("SalePriceGross__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.SalePriceGross__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("CostPriceGross__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.CostPriceGross__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("GrossProfit__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.GrossProfit__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("GrossProfitPercent__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.GrossProfitPercent__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("NumberOfGuest__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.NumberOfGuest__c))
    putRecord.addColumn(quoteColumnFamily, Bytes.toBytes("Gross_profit_per_person__c"), Bytes.toBytes(quote.Gross_profit_per_person__c))
    //addPutToList(putRecord)
    (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(quote.Id)),putRecord)
  }
  //,  @JsonProperty("CreatedDate") CreateDate: String,  @JsonProperty("LastModifiedDate") LastModifiedDate: String) extends Quote
}
```

---

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2067)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$map$1.apply(DStream.scala:558)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:726)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.withScope(StreamingContext.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.map(DStream.scala:557)
    at com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$.main(Test.scala:48)
    at com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test.main(Test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$$anon$4
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$$anon$4, value: org.json4s.DefaultFormats$$anon$4@3b954661)
    - field (class: com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$$anon$1, name: dateFormat, type: interface org.json4s.DateFormat)
    - object (class com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$$anon$1, com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$$anon$1@3e8de7fd)
    - field (class: com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$$anonfun$3, name: formats$1, type: interface org.json4s.DefaultFormats)
    - object (class com.golfbreaks.spark.streaming.Test$$anonfun$3, <function1>)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    ... 17 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the serialization stack, it seems there's a problem with the `formats` not being serializable. Instead of defining them implicitly at the beggining, you could pass them explicitly in the closure or define them as implicit vals there.

I'm not sure which method is requesting the implicit parameter, I will assume its `extract[T]`. If that's the case, you can try something like:

```scala
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY)
  .filter(_._2 != null)
  .map {
    case (_, json) =>
      implicit val formats = ...
      JsonParser.parse(json).extract[Quote] // or pass the format explicitly here
  }
```

Comment: THanks Andrei. yeah i have the similar way, where i have moved the entire parsing outside of the main class and i worked .

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :) Please don't forget to close the question